# In RStudio using bookdown, I am unable to compile a PDF version of my book. I get an error message "mathspec.sty" file not found

Tags: pdf, latex, bookdown

In RStudio (Windows 10) using bookdown, I am unable to compile a PDF version of my book.  I get an error message "mathspec.sty" file not found.  I installed it on my MikTex folder, but the error persists. How to solve this?

Then, I tried to compile to pdfdocument.  Now, I got errors from Latex because bookdown is unable to link to my preamble.tex file.  How to make preamble.tex visible?

Comment: How did you install it exactly? Did you use the MikTeX tools for installing add-on packages?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the latex _engine to pdflatex in the output.yml configuration file. This solved the problem for me, although I would still like to know how to use xelatex (i.e. where to include the mathspec.sty file).